# Access 365: find earliest Date in Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I made some mistakes with the normalization of my tables. Now my table looks something like this:

```
ID    Date1         Date2          Date 3
----------------------------------------------
1     2014-01-02    2015-01-02
2     2014-01-02                   2015-01-03
...
```

I thought I could just use the `IIF` function in a query and could compare those dates and return the lowest value. The Problem is, there are NULL Values which are returned and make the function worthless.

So my problem is: how can I return the lowest of the three in a query without wrong results because of the NULL-Values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Iif`, but you will have to care about the the NULL-Values too.

So instead of `Date1` use `Nz(Date1, CDate("31.12.9999"))` and so on.

As an alternative you could use this `MinDate` procedure in a query:

`SELECT MinDate([Date1],[Date2],[Date3]) AS MinDate FROM Table1`

```
Public Function MinDate(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Date
    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In values: Do
        If VarType(value) <> vbDate Then Exit Do
        If CLng(MinDate) = 0 Then
            MinDate = value
        Else
            If value < MinDate Then MinDate = value
        End If
    Loop While False: Next value
End Function
```

But both approaches surely smell...
You should think about a redesign.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL `Min` aggregate function will give you what you need, but first you must get those date values into a single column.  Use a `UNION` query for that.

```sql
SELECT sub.ID, Min(sub.Date_field) AS MinOfDate_field
FROM
    (
        SELECT y1.ID, y1.Date1 AS Date_field
        FROM [YourTable] AS y1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y2.ID, y2.Date2 AS Date_field
        FROM [YourTable] AS y2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y3.ID, y3.Date3 AS Date_field
        FROM [YourTable] AS y3
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.ID;
```

If you need other `YourTable` fields in your final query, `INNER JOIN` this query to the table.